# New to testing with swift (quick/nimble), trying to get past oauth screen

Tags: ios, swift, unit-testing, testing, oauth-2.0

I'm attempting to write a quick/nimble test that will just confirm a few things on the screen after my opening screen.  The opening screen is simply a button which leads to oauth2 sign in to validate users.  I'm just wondering how it is I can spoof a sign in so that I can get to the next screen.  I know this is probably not a lot of information but I'm really new to the testing aspect of swift as a whole but I know it's very important to have unit tests.

Here is code that might help:

```
import UIKit


class ViewController: UIViewController, GIDSignInDelegate, GIDSignInUIDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var signInButton: GIDSignInButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var errorLabel: UILabel!

    var googleViewController: GoogleViewController!
    var permittedList:[String] = ["me@mysite.com"]
    let env = NSProcessInfo.processInfo().environment

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor(rgb: 0x6a737b)
        super.viewDidLoad()
        GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().delegate = self
        GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().uiDelegate = self
        GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().clientID = env["CLIENT_ID"] as? String
        GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().signInSilently()
    }


    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }


    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        if segue.identifier == "googledisplay" {
            googleViewController = segue.destinationViewController as! GoogleViewController
        }
    }


    func signIn(signIn: GIDSignIn!, didSignInForUser user: GIDGoogleUser!, withError error: NSError!) {
        if let err = error {
            println(error)
        }
        else {
            if !contains(permittedList, GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().currentUser.profile.email) {
                GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().signOut()
                GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().disconnect()
                self.errorLabel.text = "You must sign in with a permitted email address"
            }
            else{
                self.errorLabel.text = ""
                performSegueWithIdentifier("googledisplay", sender: self)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

test:

```
import Foundation
import Quick
import Nimble
import PasswordRecovery

class PasswordViewControllerSpec: QuickSpec {
    var viewController = PasswordViewController()
    override func spec() {
        let _ = PasswordViewController().view
        viewController.setNewEmail("s@s.com")
        viewController.setNewLRA("unknown")
        viewController.reset_code(t: 1447267160)
        expect(self.viewController.getLRA()).to(equal("LRA"))
    }
}
```

PasswordViewController is the name of the view which is loaded after the original screen.  Thank you for any help, if there is anything more needed please tell me!